# Bad math delimiter in tikz tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, trees, rubber

I'm trying to diagram an extensive form game using TikZ trees. The following code generates errors at compile time. Specifically, it complains about missing `$`'s and a bad math delimiter. I've been over the brackets with a fine-tooth comb and I can't find where the error is being generated.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[%
   %%% Styles
   player/.style={draw,circle},
   level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm}
   %every node/.style={node distance=1cm}
   ]
   %%% Nodes
   \node [player] (root) {1}
     child { node [player] (2a) {2} 
       child { node (aa) {
         \[ \begin{array}{c}
           1 \\ 2
         \end{array} \]} 
         edge from parent
         node [left] {A} 
       }
       child { node (ab) {
         \[ \begin{array}{c}
           3 \\ 4
         \end{array} \]}
         edge from parent
         node [right] {B}
       }
       edge from parent
       node [left] {A}
     }
     child { node [player] (2b) {2}
       child { node (ba) {
         \[ \begin{array}{c}
           5 \\ 6
         \end{array} \]} 
         edge from parent
         node [left] {A} 
       }
       child { node (bb) {
         \[ \begin{array}{c}
           7 \\ 8
         \end{array} \]} 
         edge from parent
         node [right] {B}
       } 
       edge from parent
       node [right] {B}
     };
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The relevant error log output looks like

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.48 };
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.48 };
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
```

Can anyone explain what is causing these errors? It usually wouldn't be a problem, but I use `rubber` to compile from `org-mode`, and these errors are tripping it up. (These errors also trip up `texi2dvi`, for those interested.)

Comment: OK, so `s/\[|\]/$/g` seems to fix things with `rubber`. Does anyone know why `arrays` wouldn't play nice in `displaymath` environments?

Comment: jrhorn424: `array` works fine also in `displaymath` environments, but the latter not in nodes. How should they be centered and what would be the spacing before and after if they stand alone in a node? A `parbox` or `minipage` would fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$...$` instead of `\[ ... \]` and it can be compiled.

Displayed math, even if done by `$$ ... $$`, doesn't directly work in TikZ tree nodes. You probably dont't need it. Regarding the font size, you could use `\displaystyle` if necessary.

Comment: Or you can use `\(…\)`