# TeX compilers/wrappers and robustness

Tags: errors, compiling, org-mode

Please see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12571/bad-math-delimiter-in-tikz-tree) for context.

We can use `texi2dvi` to get LaTeX to compile the correct number of times, and to insert a `bibtex` call into the loop if necessary. `rubber` is another [wrapper script](https://launchpad.net/rubber) that can accomplish the same thing. (I've even heard of `latexmk` through TextMate.)

The problem is that both wrappers fail on a compiler error (`pdflatex` by default). This is a problem since I'm using `org-mode` as a front end and I'm often not notified of small errors when using wrappers. Sometimes, changing a document and introducing an error can reset counters and I won't notice the counts are busted until I print out the document.

Running `pdflatex` many times manually in `nonstopmode` seems to avoid these problems, and counters work as expected.

Do you know of any more latex wrappers, ones that might be more robust to these small errors? Are there any flags I can pass to the existing wrappers to make them "keep truckin'"?

Comment: I think my answer below may not address your question, and now I also think I don't understand the question. But leaving the answer for the moment. Can you clarify what behavior you would want from such a wrapper? Why is the wrapper failing on a compiler error a problem? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: @Faheem the wrapper would ideally do two things (in addition to correctly guessing the right number of times to run each compilation command): 1) not stop on error and 2) be verbose. It doesn't need to do these by default, but the only ones I have used so far are `texi2dvi` and `rubber`, and neither seem to have these features.

Comment: If you mean cleanly exit instead of sitting at a prompt, latexmk definitely does. The docs say to put $pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode'; in .latexmkrc, for example. Do you want me to dig out a reference?

Comment: @Faheem: No, thanks for the offer. I hadn't looked at latexmk outside of using it in TextMate a handful of times. I'll try compiling a few documents and look into the latexmk docs. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I added the link I got the incantation above from to my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

latexmk can be configured to not stop on an error, and can be run in daemon mode, recompiling when the document is updated. I'm not aware if rubber has these features as well. My impression is that latexmk is the most widely used program that handles this kind of TeX/LaTeX compilation/recompilation, and is quite full-featured and reliable. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738755/dont-make-me-manually-abort-a-latex-compile-when-theres-an-error for a self-described "Mini-tutorial on latexmk".

EDIT: I am currently using `SCons` to handle my LaTeX builds, since it has reasonable support for TeX, and also I use `SCons` for my general build needs. A minimal example looks like

```
env = Environment()
env.Program(target='foo', 'foo.tex')
```

I think the support for TeX is not as robust in `SCons` as for example `latexmk`, but it integrates nicely with the rest of my build if I use it this way, and I can do extra programming if necessary. SCons also runs `TeX` commands in nonstop mode. It is configurable via environment variables, which is handy.

Answer (score 2):

I last looked at rubber two or three years ago, when I think it did not support pdflatex. It appears to now, but I don't see any documentation for it. It says it supports pdflatex in the newest version.

Clearly texi2dvi won't work-- it produces a dvi which means latex, not pdflatex.

latexmk has worked well for me in the past, though I haven't tried it with org-mode. Though you may want to take a look at this [Emacs-org-mode and latexmk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10562/emacs-org-mode-and-latexmk)

Comment: thanks for the link! I accidentally ran into that post yesterday when looking for the `org-mode` tag. Also, you make a great point about texi2dvi.